# PyQt5.QtSql.QSqlError while inserting lineEdit input into database

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to insert the `QLineEdit` input into a database

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg

from PyQt5 import QtSql as qsql


class Secondwindow(qtw.QWidget):
    '''
    description einfügen
    '''

    # Attribut Signal

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # your code will go here

        # Messung starten
        self.connectdb_button = qtw.QPushButton("Connect to Database ?")
        hlaout_layout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        hlaout_layout.addStretch(1)
        hlaout_layout.addWidget(self.connectdb_button)
        hlaout_layout.addStretch(1)

        # input /nested layout
        input1_label = qtw.QLabel("input 1 ")
        self.input_1 = qtw.QLineEdit()
        input1_hlayout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        input1_hlayout.addStretch(1)
        input1_hlayout.addWidget(input1_label)
        input1_hlayout.addWidget(self.input_1)
        input1_hlayout.addStretch(1)
        input1_hlayout.setAlignment(qtc.Qt.AlignHCenter)

        input2_label = qtw.QLabel("input 2 ")
        self.input_2 = qtw.QLineEdit()
        input2_hlayout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        input2_hlayout.addStretch(1)
        input2_hlayout.addWidget(input2_label)
        input2_hlayout.addWidget(self.input_2)
        input2_hlayout.addStretch(1)
        input2_hlayout.setAlignment(qtc.Qt.AlignHCenter)

        input3_label = qtw.QLabel("input 3 ")
        self.input_3 = qtw.QLineEdit()
        input3_hlayout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        input3_hlayout.addStretch(1)
        input3_hlayout.addWidget(input3_label)
        input3_hlayout.addWidget(self.input_3)
        input3_hlayout.addStretch(1)
        input3_hlayout.setAlignment(qtc.Qt.AlignHCenter)

        input4_label = qtw.QLabel("input 4 ")
        self.input_4 = qtw.QLineEdit()
        input4_hlayout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        input4_hlayout.addStretch(1)
        input4_hlayout.addWidget(input4_label)
        input4_hlayout.addWidget(self.input_4)
        input4_hlayout.addStretch(1)
        input4_hlayout.setAlignment(qtc.Qt.AlignHCenter)

        input5_label = qtw.QLabel("input 5 ")
        self.input_5 = qtw.QLineEdit()
        input5_hlayout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        input5_hlayout.addStretch(1)
        input5_hlayout.addWidget(input5_label)
        input5_hlayout.addWidget(self.input_5)
        input5_hlayout.addStretch(1)
        input5_hlayout.setAlignment(qtc.Qt.AlignHCenter)

        # select button
        self.select_button = qtw.QPushButton("start query ")
        select_buttonlayout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        select_buttonlayout.setAlignment(qtc.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        select_buttonlayout.addStretch(1)
        select_buttonlayout.addWidget(self.select_button)
        select_buttonlayout.addStretch(1)

        # hauptlayout
        haupt_layout = qtw.QFormLayout()

        haupt_layout.addRow(self.connectdb_button)
        haupt_layout.setVerticalSpacing(20)
        haupt_layout.addRow(input1_hlayout)
        haupt_layout.setVerticalSpacing(20)
        haupt_layout.addRow(input2_hlayout)
        haupt_layout.setVerticalSpacing(20)
        haupt_layout.addRow(input3_hlayout)
        haupt_layout.setVerticalSpacing(20)
        haupt_layout.addRow(input4_hlayout)
        haupt_layout.setVerticalSpacing(20)
        haupt_layout.addRow(input5_hlayout)
        haupt_layout.setVerticalSpacing(30)
        haupt_layout.addRow(select_buttonlayout)

        self.setLayout(haupt_layout)

        self.show()

        # Funktionalität
        self.connectdb_button.clicked.connect(self.connect_to_db)

        self.select_button.clicked.connect(self.query_data)

    def connect_to_db(self):
        self.database = qsql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        self.database.setDatabaseName('qtdatabase.db')
        self.database.open()
        if self.database.isOpen():
            qtw.QMessageBox.about(self, 'connectet', "connection to db successful")

        # einfügen siehe pdf
        # if not self.db.open():
        #     error = self.db.lastError().text()
        # qtw.QMessageBox.critical(
        #     None, 'DB Connection Error',
        #     'Could not open database file: '
        #     f'{error}')
        # sys.exit(1)

    def query_data(self):
        mein_input = []

        item1 = self.input_1.text()
        item2 = self.input_2.text()
        item3 = self.input_3.text()
        item4 = self.input_4.text()
        item5 = self.input_5.text()

        mein_input.append(item1)
        mein_input.append(item2)
        mein_input.append(item3)
        mein_input.append(item4)
        mein_input.append(item5)

        self.query = qsql.QSqlQuery()
        self.query.prepare("INSERT INTO userinput(firstcolumns) VALUES(?)")

        self.query.addBindValue(mein_input)

        if not self.query.execBatch():
            print(self.query.lastError().text())

        self.close()
        # if not self.database.isOpen():
        #     qtw.QMessageBox.about(self, 'Erfolg', "Data inserted successfully")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Secondwindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I get this error

> Parameter count mismatch

When I insert a list instead of the LineEdit input the function works fine.

I checked that the table exists in the database also the column
output: `['firstcolumns']`

```
import sqlite3

# connect to database query starten
try:
    db_connection = sqlite3.connect("qtdatabase.db")

    cursor = db_connection.cursor()

    column_abfrage = '''SELECT * FROM userinput;'''

    cursor.execute(column_abfrage)
    cursor.close()

    names = list(map(lambda x: x[0], cursor.description))

    print(names)

except sqlite3.Error as error:
    print(error)

finally:
    if (db_connection):
        db_connection.close()
        print("db connection closed")
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO userinput(firs`?, change `print(self.query.lastError())` to `print(self.query.lastError().text())`

Comment: I get know a `Parameter count mismatch` Error

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Are you sure you have successfully connected to the database or does the "userinput" table exist and has the "firstcolumns" field? I only get that error when the above is not fulfilled.

Comment: yes I insert the data in an existing table with the colum name firstcolumns here is the code [code](https://gist.github.com/JosephCurvin/cc2f1be4eeb745074fb34b97c66753be)

Comment: Edit your question and place the code there. On the other hand, share the qtdatabase.db to verify if the table exists.

Comment: also change all `mein_input.extend(xxx)` to `mein_input.append(xxx)`

Comment: execute `print(self.database.tables())` on query_data method

Comment: also execute `record = self.database.record("userinput")`
        `for i in range(record.count()):`
         `print(record.fieldName(i))`

Comment: change `self.database.setDatabaseName('qtdatabase.db')` to `self.database.setDatabaseName('/full/path/of/qtdatabase.db')`

Comment: thanks, after inserting the full path everything works fine know, that was the last thing I was thinking about because the db is in the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sqlite` is a database that has a particular characteristic: If the database does not exist when you try to open then it will be created so the `open()` method will always return True so it can generate silent problems.

In this case it is always advisable to use the full path, this can be explicitly: "/full/path/of/database" or built based on the location of the script, for example if the database is in the same script folder then you can use the following code:

```py
import os

# ...

current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
db_path = os.path.join(current_dir, "qtdatabase.db")
self.database = qsql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
self.database.setDatabaseName(db_path)
if self.database.open():
    qtw.QMessageBox.about(self, 'connectet', "connection to db successful")
```

In your case you are probably using some IDE that when running the script uses a working directory different from the location of the script.